# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, file, dllimport

I've created a  dll in c++. I've a function in that dll which contains the following code.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunction(CString strPath)
{
    BYTE startBuffer[] = { 80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    FILE *f = _wfopen(strPath.GetBuffer(strPath.GetLength()), _T("wb"));        
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        strPath.ReleaseBuffer();
        fwrite(startBuffer, sizeof(startBuffer), 1, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

If I comment this line and then call the dll. It won't be any problem.

The calling convention is as follows :

```
[DllImport("OutExt.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern void MyFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strPath);
```

someone please help me out for this problem.

Comment: We cannot help you until you provide real details. Show an entire problem. The entire C++ function that you are calling. And the entire C# code that calls it. Don't show your entire projects. Cut it down to a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you help now. If you want you can just put both of the code as in dll project and c# project. Then you can just find it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CString` is a native C++ class that cannot be marshalled using p/invoke. You will need to use a pointer null-terminated character array.

Either:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunction(const char *strPath)
```

if you must restrict yourself to the legacy ANSI code page, or

```
__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunction(const wchar_t *strPath)
```

for Unicode.

On the C# side the declarations would be:

```
[DllImport("OutExt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void MyFunction(string strPath);
```

and

```
[DllImport("OutExt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void MyFunction(string strPath);
```

respectively.